# how can I make delay in shader?

Tags: unity, shaders, sprites, fragment-shader, shaderlab

[image: swordgif]

my effect is loop but I need have delay between each flash effect.i don't want use c# code because i believe there is easy way to implement delay in shader.

```
waitfor 2 second
flash effect
waitfor 2 second
flash effect
....
```

this is my shader:

```
Shader "Smkgames/SwordFlash" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex("MainTex",2D) = "white"{}
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _LineColor ("LineColor", Color) = (1,1,0,1)
        _Speed ("Speed",Float) = 1
        _Thickness ("Thickness", Float) = 4.286548
        _LineSeparation ("LineSeparation", Range(0.1, 10)) = 1
        _LineRotation ("LineRotation", Range(-180, 180)) = 0
        _Numbers ("Numbers", Float ) = 1
        [MaterialToggle] _Enable ("Enable", Float ) = 1
        _Mask ("Mask", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {
               Tags {
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }
ZWrite Off Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

Pass
{
Name "Sprite"

CGPROGRAM
#pragma vertex vert
#pragma fragment frag
#pragma fragmentoption ARB_precision_hint_fastest
#include "UnityCG.cginc"

struct VertexInput
{
float4 vertex   : POSITION;
float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
};

struct VertexOutput
{
float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
half2 uv  : TEXCOORD0;
};

sampler2D _MainTex;
float4 _MainTex_ST;
fixed4 _Color;
float _Speed;
float _Numbers;


VertexOutput vert(VertexInput v)
{
VertexOutput o;
o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX (v.uv, _MainTex);
return o;
}

float4 frag (VertexOutput i) : COLOR
{

float2 uv = i.uv.xy;
    float4 tex = tex2D(_MainTex, uv);

return tex*_Color;
}
ENDCG
}


        Tags {
            "IgnoreProjector"="True"
            "Queue"="Transparent"
            "RenderType"="Transparent"
        }
        Pass {
            Name "FlashEffect"
            Blend One One
            ZWrite Off

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #define UNITY_PASS_FORWARDBASE
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #pragma multi_compile_fwdbase
            #pragma only_renderers d3d9 d3d11 glcore gles n3ds wiiu 
            #pragma target 3.0
            uniform float4 _TimeEditor;
            uniform float _LineAlpha;
            uniform float _Speed;
            uniform float _Thickness;
            uniform float _LineSeparation;
            uniform float _LineRotation;
            uniform float4 _LineColor;
            uniform float _Numbers;
            uniform fixed _Enable;
            uniform sampler2D _Mask; uniform float4 _Mask_ST;
            sampler2D _MainTex;
            struct VertexInput {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord0 : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            struct VertexOutput {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uv0 : TEXCOORD0;
            };
            VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
                VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
                o.uv0 = v.texcoord0;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex );
                return o;
            }
            float4 frag(VertexOutput i) : COLOR {
                float4 _Mask_var = tex2D(_Mask,TRANSFORM_TEX(i.uv0, _Mask));
                float node_9529_ang = (_LineRotation*0.01745333+0.0);
                float node_9529_spd = 1.0;
                float node_9529_cos = cos(node_9529_spd*node_9529_ang);
                float node_9529_sin = sin(node_9529_spd*node_9529_ang);
                float2 node_9529_piv = float2(0.5,0.5);
                float2 node_9529 = (mul(float2((i.uv0.r/_LineSeparation),(i.uv0.g/_LineSeparation))-node_9529_piv,float2x2( node_9529_cos, -node_9529_sin, node_9529_sin, node_9529_cos))+node_9529_piv);
                float4 node_5664 = _Time + _TimeEditor;
                float node_6322 = frac((_Numbers*(1.0 - (node_9529+(node_5664.g*_Speed))).g));
                float node_4443 = (pow(smoothstep( 0.5, 0.0, ((1.0 - node_6322)*node_6322) ),(35.0-_Thickness))*_LineColor.a);
                float3 emissive = lerp( ((node_4443*_LineColor.rgb)), 0.0, 1-_Enable )*_Mask_var.a;
                float3 finalColor = emissive;
                return fixed4(finalColor,1)*tex2D(_MainTex,i.uv0).a*_Mask_var.x;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
Fallback "Sprites/Default"
}
```

Comment: finally i define a variable as `_AnimationTime` and use it for changing line movement `float4 node_5664 = _AnimationTime;` then I easily change it by animation component.

Answer (score 1):

To create a pause what you need to do is to scale and clamp your time.

As your animation time is already exactly 1 second long and you want a 2 second pause (1+2 = 3) you will need to:

- divide your time by 3 (multiply by 1.0/3.0)
- keep the fractional part as you're doing already,
- multiply by 3 (back to normal time scale)
- then clamp the animation value between 0 and 1 (your original animation length).

The line:

`float node_6322 = frac((_Numbers*(1.0 - (node_9529+(node_5664.g*_Speed))).g));`

Need to be changed to:

`float node_6322 = clamp(frac( (_Numbers*(1.0 - (node_9529+(node_5664.g*_Speed))).g) * (1.0/3.0)) * 3.0, 0.0, 1.0)`;

This will extend the animation to 3 seconds total (1 second animation + 2 seconds pause) but the clamp part stops the animation at the loop point (1.0).

You'll have to insure the pause point is at the start/end (loop point) of your animation, which usually it is.